# wlan0: link is not ready

Tags: networking, wifi, debian, wpa

I have had my pi3 for a while now all of a sudden I start to get

> IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready 
>   IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready

and stalls there until I restart the system. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

What could be the problem? What should I be looking at for the fault?

**UPDATE**

My `dmesg`

```
>  6.182631] brcmfmac: Firmware version = wl0: Oct 23 2017 03:55:53 version 7.45.98.38 (r674442 CY) FWID 01-e58d219f [    6.198918]
> brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: CLM version = API: 12.2 Data: 7.11.15
> Compiler: 1.24.2 ClmImport: 1.24.1 Creation: 2014-05-26 10:53:55 Inc
> Data: 9.10.39 Inc Compiler: 1.29.4 Inc ClmImport: 1.36.3 Creation:
> 2017-10-23 03:47:14  [    6.349557] brcmfmac: power management
> disabled [    8.673118]  sda: sda1 sda2 [    8.684376] sd 0:0:0:0:
> [sda] Attached SCSI disk [    9.197354] EXT4-fs (sda2): recovery
> complete [    9.206534] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with
> ordered data mode. Opts: (null) [   13.924815] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0
> eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup [   13.936968] IPv6:
> ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready [   14.000865] IPv6:
> ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready [   14.011252] brcmfmac:
> power management disabled [   14.370071] NFSD: starting 90-second
> grace period (net ffffff8d64286680) [   14.792240] IPv6:
> ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready [   23.164632]
> cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will
> be ignored [   24.871204] Adding 194768k swap on 4.  Priority:-1
> extents:2 across:243920k FS [   25.155197] Adding 154276k swap on 1. 
> Priority:-2 extents:10 across:368636k FS [   38.657491] bridge:
> filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default.
> Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this. [  
> 38.677629] Bridge firewalling registered
```

Comment: since the raspberry pi 3 is only 2.5 years old `Announced on 29th Feb 2016`, you started your question badly :p anyway, I think it's actually the NEXT step in the boot process that is at fault. When it successfully boots, what is shown after `wlan0: link becomes ready`

Comment: OK, this pretty much just confirms you  original post.So -SOP - when did you  last run update / upgrade ? Can you backup you SD BEFORE you do update / upgrade - just to be safe?

Comment: @JanHus will have to try this as I'm using HypriotOS. I was consulting the group forums for answers so will keep looking

Comment: OK, hope I won't get into trouble "discussing ". I run dmesg on my latest Rasopian.I do not have wlan0 activated , but I see similar output you  have expereinceds on my USB wlan1 - basically ln endless loop [94204.726521] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
[94204.726610] brcmfmac: power management disabled
[94520.691424] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
[94520.691444] brcmfmac: power management disabled

Answer (score 1):

> > IPv6: ADDRCONF (NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready IPv6:
> > ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
>
> and stalls there until I restart the system.

You can shutdown the radio with `nmcli`. [`nmcli`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nmcli) is the network manager command line interface.

```
nmcli radio wifi off
```

I use IPv4 wired LAN connection, and I do nothing with Wifi or IPv6. The kicker for me was, an unused radio was killing my LAN connection every half hour. Every half hour I was getting a new IPv4 address, which killed my SSH connection.

We think we tracked it down to RFC 3041, [Privacy Extensions for Stateless Address Autoconfiguration in IPv6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3041). I have no idea why Wireless IPv6 was interfering with my Wired IPv4 addresses. But killing the radio solved the problem.

(My DHCP server also has one hour leases to aggressively scavenge IP addresses. The Raspberry Pi 3 B+ is the only device that has had problems with it. Also running Fedora 29 Aarch64 image).

---

> What could be the problem? What should I be looking at for the fault?

Who knows. I miss the old days when things just worked.

Comment: There is no network manager installed on a Raspberry Pi by default and there is no program `nmcli` available.